# Laravel 5.3 Eloquent Column not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have been strugling with understanding the eloquent relationships this whole day and now i decided to post my issue here. I'm getting an error when trying to save an entry in the database.

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'address' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `invoices` (`address`, `invoice`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (3, 2, 1, 2016-12-25 23:34:44, 2016-12-25 23:34:44))

**InvoiceController**

```
public function postInvoiceDetails(Request $request)
{
    $invoice = new Invoice();
    $invoice->address = $request['customer-address'];
    $invoice->invoice = $request['invoice-number'];
    $request->user()->invoices()->save($invoice);
}
```

**User-model**

```
public function addresses()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Address');
}

public function invoices()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Invoice');
}
```

**Address-model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**Invoice-model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Address');
}
```

**Invoices-table**

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->integer('address_id');
$table->integer('invoice_number');
$table->timestamps();
```

**Addresses-table**

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->text('address');
$table->timestamps();
```

What i am trying to do is:

1. An user can have many invoices
2. User can have many addresses (customer addresses)
3. Invoice has one address is assigned one address_id (id from addresses-table)

What i found out: Changing address function in Invoice-model to **address_id()** solves the issue, however this shouldn't be needed if i understand the relationships correctly and what happens next is that i get the same error but now with the "invoice" field and at this point i suspect badly defined relationships. Thanks for any help.

Comment: The error indicates there is no address field in your database. Check the database to see if the column address exists in the table invoices.

Comment: The tables are exactly as posted above. The Invoice-table has an address_id field, that should be correct for what i'm trying to achieve right?

Answer (score 1):

Error is expected, because you are storing address not the address_id, I had worked on the same problem and here is the way I did it.

```
$address = Address::create($address_data);
$invoice_data['address_id'] = $address->id;
```

now you are storing a reference to address in your invoice table.

Comment: Where does the variable $address_data come from?

Comment: Thats for reference, that data is nothing but the data that you will insert in to address table.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the foreign key field like this:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Address', 'address_id');
```

Comment: I did try that as i seen in the eloquent docs however it doesn't work for me as i still get the same identical error.